# Cargar datos en una tabla sin ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

esta es la primera pregunta que hago en este medio, soy nuevo en cuanto a programacion WEB y me estan costando ciertas cosas.

Tengo un inconveniente al cargar datos, a ver si me explico bien:

- Estoy usando php y javascrip para un proyecto de la universidad es referente a una empresa constructora.
- Para este formulario de ALTAS necesito cargar los servicios que ofrece esta empresa constructora e indicar cuales son los materiales que utiliza al hacer este servicio, como tambien la cantidad a utilizar por cada metro de este servicio
- Al crear nuevo servicio ya debo  indicar los materiales a ulizar, estos ya existen en la base de datos
- Al hacer click en OK necesito que ese material ingresado se muestre en una tabla debajo. y asi sucesivamente hasta cargar todos los materiales que se van a utilizar.
- Solo al finalizar toda la carga de materiales a utilizar
- Yo se que esto se puede hacer con ajax, pero no tengo ningun conocimiento de ajax y ya no me da el tiempo. Si tienen algun ejemplo pequeño con ajax igual creo que me serviria.

Agradezco a todos por la ayuda.
Saludos
[image: Esto es lo que tengo]

[image: Necesito algo asi]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debemos aclarar primero si lo que necesitás es que la data **se muestre en la tabla de abajo** o si necesitás que la data **se muestre en la tabla de abajo y se guarde en la base de datos**.

Si es la primera, podés hacer un script que tome los valores de la forma, y con ello cree dinámicamente una nueva fila en la tabla de abajo.

```js
document.getElementById('botonOk').addEventListener('click', agregarFila);
(function(){
  // Obtener todos los elementos boton-eliminar
  // que ya están cargados
  let botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton-eliminar');
  
  // Agregar listener a todos los botones
  botones.forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener('click', eliminarFila);
  });
})();

function agregarFila(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  let campo1 = document.createElement('td');
  let campo2 = document.createElement('td');
  let campo3 = document.createElement('td');
  
  // Crear campo botón con un botón adentro
  let campoEliminar = document.createElement('td');
  let botonEliminar = document.createElement('button');
  
  botonEliminar.type = 'button';
  botonEliminar.innerText = 'Eliminar';
  botonEliminar.className='boton-eliminar';
  // Agregar función listener al botón
  botonEliminar.addEventListener('click', eliminarFila);
  
  campo1.innerText = document.getElementById('campo1').value;
  campo2.innerText = document.getElementById('campo2').value;
  campo3.innerText = document.getElementById('campo3').value;
  
  campoEliminar.appendChild(botonEliminar);
  
  let nuevaFila = document.createElement('tr');
  nuevaFila.appendChild(campo1);
  nuevaFila.appendChild(campo2);
  nuevaFila.appendChild(campo3);
  nuevaFila.appendChild(campoEliminar);
  
  document.getElementById('tablaDestino').querySelector('tbody').appendChild(nuevaFila);
}

function eliminarFila(event){
  // Obtener nodo fila que contiene el botón
  let fila = this.parentElement.parentElement;
  fila.remove();
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1" />
    <input type="text" name="campo2" id="campo2" />
    <input type="text" name="campo3" id="campo3" />
    <button type="button" id="botonOk">Agregar</button>
</form>
<table id="tablaDestino">
    <thead>
        <th>Campo 1</th>
        <th>Campo 2</th>
        <th>Campo 3</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Precargado 1</td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="boton-eliminar">Eliminar</button>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Si necesitás guardarlo en la base de datos, podés usar el mismo método para mostrar la data, y al final de la función `agregarFila` hacer una llamada asíncrona (AJAX) para insertar el registro. Cabe mencionar que en el snippet no están consideradas las validaciones necesarias para insertar la data (integridad de datos, campos no-vacíos, etc).

Comment: Desde ya, te agradezco la ayuda. Efectivamente necesito que la data se vea en la tabla de abajo, pero sin guardar los datos aun. Los datos se almacenaran  a la base de datos al final. Voy a probar con el codigo que me das, avisare como me fue

Comment: Podés tomar la implementación de arriba (adaptada para que refleje los campos de tu tabla) para que las filas se creen dinámicamente en la tabla.

Comment: Niche, muchisimas gracias, funciona genial. Eres muy amable

Comment: Hola Niche, tu solucion me parecio perfecta, me ayudo bastante, pero ahora tengo otra duda, ¿Como puedo agregarle un boton a la tabla, para quitar una fila? (En el hipotetico caso de que el usuario se haya equivocado y quiera quitarlo)

Comment: Agregué nueva funcionalidad al código para eliminar las filas de forma dinámica.

Comment: Te agradezco infinitamente, me has ayudado bastante. Saludos!!!

Comment: Hola @Niche, perdona que te escriba aqui, quisiera pedirte otra ayuda y como tu me resolviste mis dudas anteriores te lo pregunto aqui.  Una vez guardados los datos de la tabla que me hiciste. las quiero modificar o agregar mas registros, el caso es que los registros ya almacenados los muestro con php normalcito, y una vez que le agrego mas filas con el codigo que me pasaste no me los guarda, debo guardar solo con los que cargue en php o solo lo que se carga con el codigo que me facilitaste, me gustaria saber como estirar los datos de la base de datos a esa tabla, pero con ajax.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205310/rellenar-tabla-con-ajax-desde-una-base-de-datos